# Draw a ring shape with fading edges?

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, edges, fading

How can I get a ring shape with fading edges in a drawable? I've tried this, but it's not working

```
<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="3dp"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#DDDDDD"
            android:endColor="#33DDDDDD"
            android:useLevel="false" 
            android:type="sweep"/>
        <size
            android:height="80dip"
            android:width="80dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: You may need to use `radial` as the type, then specify the colours and radius.

Comment: How does your current code differ from your desired outcome? "Not working" is not very descriptive.